# How to add a dash sign (-) before each line in UITextview ?1

Tags: ios, uitextview

Im developing an app for iPhone, and I want to add a dash sign (-) or any other sign at the beginning of each line in a UITextView which has some multilines text in it..
I want the text to appear as a points

```
- abc

- def

- ghi
```

like this..

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it with a NSMutableString like this:

```
    NSMutableString *temp = [self.textView.text mutableCopy];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"\n- " options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, temp.length)];
    self.textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"- %@", temp];
```

But with this you have to check, so that you don't have two "- " if you do it twice. So only do this for output, not for the text itself.

Comment: You're welcome. I forgot to mention that you have to add the first "- " by yourself. Maybe with self.textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"- %@",temp]; instead of the last line.